# I require help to fill this custom library spinner with items from programmatic string array

Tags: android, mysql, json

I am using this searchable spinner https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner/

I am receiving my JSON result from php and then parsing it to a string array using this code

```
try {
JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(result);
JSONObject json = null;
fullname = new String[JA.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++) {
json = JA.getJSONObject(i);
fullname[i] = json.getString("fullname");
}
//    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Loaded", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
for (int i = 0; i < fullname.length; i++) {
instslist.add(fullname[i]); 
}
```

and i am using this to fill the spinner

```
instSpinner.findViewById(R.id.floatspinner);
        instSpinner.setTitle("Select Instructor");
        instSpinner.setPositiveButton("OK");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, instNames);
        dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        instSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);
```

but nothing is showing up in the list. Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instSpinner. findViewById(R.id.floatspinner);

should be

instSpinner = (SearchableSpinner) findViewById(R.id.floatspinner);

Answer (score 0):

You are filling the JSON data in `instslist` but you are using `instNames`

Make sure the `List` you are using has data, and otherwise this library should work exactly like the default `Spinner` in android

Comment: It uses fullname array not instNames like im using. Which doesn't work either and i compiled the code in netbeans to check if the array has the parsed json data and it does. No idea why this is not working.